# Laravel - Pre populating insertion screens with dummy data?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have `form.blade.php` which handles the same create/update html elements for my users.

In addition, I have an 'enhanced' html element which is rendered by JS later on to create a nicer element (kinda like a radio button).

The element's markup goes as:

```
    <ul class="form_opt" data-id="is_public">
    <li class="text-label">Profile Access</li>
    <li><a href="" class="last<?= ( $user->is_public == 0 ) ? ' current' : NULL ?>" data-value="0">Private</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="first<?= ( $user->is_public == 1 ) ? ' current' : NULL ?>" data-value="1">Public</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that on the `add` screen, I don't have a `$user` object (since im not editing any user...), I thought about creating `$user` instance as stdClass in the `create` method, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not create a dummy user object, just pass in a value of null for `$user` and update your ternary to handle it:

```
<a href="" class="last<?= ( $user && $user->is_public == 0 ) ? ' current' : '' ?>" data-value="0">
    Private
</a>
```

Comment: Tried that too, thought there might be an other option...thanks!